# How do I run all batch files under directory and sub directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

Here is my code:

```
@echo off 
 for /R %%x in (*.bat) do ( 
 call %%x 
)
pause
```

I'm trying to find all batch files under my directory and its sub directory.
When I echo the result it gives me the exact location of the file but when I try to change the echo to call to run the batch files I get errors, for example:

> 'C:\Users\Jairuz\Downloads\web' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Comment: call "%%x" you have to quote paths with spaces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with string ?

```
@echo off 
 for /R %%x in (*.bat) do ( 
 call "%%x" 
)
pause
```

Path with space have to be encapsulated with (")

Answer (score 2):

Source: http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s D:\*.bat') DO start "%%G"
```

goodluck!